# How to find next element of particular style after specific button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code currently to read data from the first column of the first table:

```
jQuery(".confluenceTable tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
   projects_list.push(jQuery(this).text().trim());
});
```

Now I need to work with the first table of `.confluenceTable` located after button with `#showdata` id. How should I do it?

I tried something like

```
jQuery("#showdata").nextAll(".confluenceTable tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
```

but it returns no result.

The html looks like below

```
<button name="showdata" id="showdata" type="button"><p>show data</p></button> 
<p>some text</p>
<div class="table-wrap">
<table class="wrapped relative-table confluenceTable" style="width: 99.94%;">
```

Comment: Are these dynamic? Why not give each one a new custom class name or unique id so you can select them directly without having to traverse the DOM?

Comment: Why not `jQuery('#showdata').next('table.confluenceTable')` - that allows you to _work with the first table of .confluenceTable located after button_

Comment: is `<table class="wrapped relative-table confluenceTable" style="width: 99.94%;">` INSIDE `<div class="table-wrap">` or AFTER? cause the fact that some tags are missing their matching ends and some are not is tricking me. and in any case, will it always be that way for every table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when posting questions which are strongly related to dom querying and manipulation, please include well structured code, you should not make people go jumping unnecessary obstacles to help you.

As for the problem at hand, the main thing missing was `:first`.

The first snippet is in case the table will be INSIDE `<div class="table-wrap"></div>`, else the second snippet.

```js
var res = $('#showdata').nextAll('.table-wrap:first').children('.confluenceTable');
var projects_list=[];
res.find("tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
   projects_list.push(jQuery(this).text().trim());
});

console.log(projects_list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="showdata" id="showdata" type="button"><p>show data</p></button> 
<p>some text</p>
<div class="table-wrap">
<table class="wrapped relative-table confluenceTable" style="width: 99.94%;">
<thead><tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell3</td><td>cell4</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell5</td><td>cell6</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

```js
var res = $('#showdata').nextAll('.confluenceTable:first');
var projects_list=[];
res.find("tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
   projects_list.push(jQuery(this).text().trim());
});

console.log(projects_list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="showdata" id="showdata" type="button"><p>show data</p></button> 
<p>some text</p>
<div class="table-wrap">
</div>
<table class="wrapped relative-table confluenceTable" style="width: 99.94%;">
<thead><tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell3</td><td>cell4</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell5</td><td>cell6</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```